# How to add different where clause for nested methods

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, yii2

I have two function one is function1() and another is function2() in same class. i called first method function1() in function2() in my function1() sql query is running to get something data from database and in my second function "function2()" i want to filter my data with sql where clause property. how to append my sql query for second function.

Comment: Could you please edit-in the actual functions? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
function func1($clause = null)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * from table";

   if ( !empty($clause) )
     $sql .= ( " WHERE " . $clause );

   // ... further logic
}

function func2()
{

    $res = $this->func1("a = 'b'");

    $res2 = $this->func1();  // no were clause


    // ...

}
```